# Pasar de Json a Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo la siguiente function

```php
public function edit(categoryarea $categoryarea){
    $this->categoryarea = $categoryarea;
}
```

Estoy intentado pasar pasar esto a una `Array` para poder obtener solo **ID** de la siguinte manera:

```php
  $this->categoryareaarray = json_decode($this->categoryarea, true);
```

pero me esta devolviendo el siguiente error

```
ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

también intente la siguiente consulta

```
$this->categoryareaarray = json_encode( (array) $this->categoryarea);
```

y me devuelve esto

```
"{\"\\u0000*\\u0000guarded\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000connection\":\"mysql\",\"\\u0000*\\u0000table\":\"category_areas\",\"\\u0000*\\u0000primaryKey\":\"id\",\"\\u0000*\\u0000keyType\":\"int\",\"incrementing\":true,\"\\u0000*\\u0000with\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000withCount\":[],\"preventsLazyLoading\":false,\"\\u0000*\\u0000perPage\":15,\"exists\":true,\"wasRecentlyCreated\":false,\"\\u0000*\\u0000attributes\":{\"id\":21,\"id_category\":18,\"id_area\":9,\"ans_cat\":5,\"duration_cat\":null,\"description\":null,\"created_at\":\"2021-07-14 16:35:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-07-17 03:14:32\"},\"\\u0000*\\u0000original\":{\"id\":21,\"id_category\":18,\"id_area\":9,\"ans_cat\":5,\"duration_cat\":null,\"description\":null,\"created_at\":\"2021-07-14 16:35:28\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-07-17 03:14:32\"},\"\\u0000*\\u0000changes\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000casts\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000classCastCache\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000dates\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000dateFormat\":null,\"\\u0000*\\u0000appends\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000dispatchesEvents\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000observables\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000relations\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000touches\":[],\"timestamps\":true,\"\\u0000*\\u0000hidden\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000visible\":[],\"\\u0000*\\u0000fillable\":[]}"
```

Alguien me podría decir que estoy haciendo mal y que debo hacer para obtener el **ID** en modo de `Array`, ya que necesito el **ID** para hacer una nueva consulta..

Gracias

---

Si tomo la varible `$categoryarea` y lo paso por un **dd** me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
App\Models\categoryarea\categoryArea {#1421 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "category_areas"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 21
    "id_category" => 18
    "id_area" => 9
    "ans_cat" => 5
    "duration_cat" => null
    "description" => null
    "created_at" => "2021-07-14 16:35:28"
    "updated_at" => "2021-07-17 03:14:32"
  ]
  #original: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 21
    "id_category" => 18
    "id_area" => 9
    "ans_cat" => 5
    "duration_cat" => null
    "description" => null
    "created_at" => "2021-07-14 16:35:28"
    "updated_at" => "2021-07-17 03:14:32"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

Comment: ¿Como estas verificando que `$categoryarea` sea un totalmente un `json`? no parece serlo, podrías hacer un `var_dump` o `dd` sobre el, y colocarlo en tu pregunta por favor

Comment: @Josbert listo creo que es eso?

Comment: Perfecto amigo si es eso, pero no es una `JSON` es una instancia de **Eloquent**, no tienes que decodificarlo, solo acceder a el **id** así `$categoryarea->id`

Comment: @Josbert si amigo es lo que necesitaba gracias

Comment: Lo que sucede es que si haces algo como esto `return $categoryarea`, *Laravel* automáticamente responde con sus `#attributes` en formato de **json**, quizá por eso te confundiste un poco ;)

Comment: si y es que soy novato es esto en ton también fue por eso jejeje.. @Josbert responde la en pregunta para cerrar esto.. muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Vale dame un momento amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios `categoryarea` es un modelo de [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) al hacer algo como esto:

```php
public function edit(categoryarea $categoryarea){
   $this->categoryarea = $categoryarea;
}
```

Estas pasando a la función `edit` una instancia o mejor dicho una **collection** de **eloquent** en este caso `$categoryarea`, no necesitas pasarlo a **json** a menos que estés, trabajando en una **API** por ejemplo, en la que también con solo hacer:

```php
return $categoryarea
```

**Laravel** automáticamente pasara a **JSON** sus atributos y responderá con elló. Solo necesitas obtener el **id** o cualquiera de sus atributos con la sintaxis de [objeto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php)

```php
$categoryarea->id
```

---

##### Finalmente respondiendo al titulo de tu pregunta:

Para decodificar un **json** en un **Array asociativo** puedes usar la función [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) de **PHP**

```php
// El segundo parámetro en true, indica que se pasara a un array asociativo 
json_decode($miJSON, true);
```